# How do I return Message error for PROTECT Field on DJANGO

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I don't how return a simple message for a error on django, for example, I neeed return PROTECT Error on delete this OBJECT:

**MY VIEW:**

```
    def delete_notafiscal(request, notafiscal_id):
        notafiscal = NotaFiscal.objects.get(id=notafiscal_id)
        context={'object':notafiscal,'forms':''}
        try:
            if request.method =="POST":
                notafiscal.delete()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("controles:notasfiscais"))
            
        except ProtectedError as e:
            print("erro",e)
        
        return render(request,'controles/notafiscal_confirm_delete.html',context)
```

**MY TEMPLATE**

```
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <p>Você irá deletar "{{ object }}"?</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
    </form>
```

**MODELS**

```
    class NotaFiscal(models.Model):
        nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        documento = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/notafiscal/')
      
    class Item(models.Model):
        id_item = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        id_notafiscal = models.ForeignKey(NotaFiscal, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null = True)
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should be something like:

```
def delete_notafiscal(request, notafiscal_id):
    try:
        notafiscal = NotaFiscal.objects.get(id=notafiscal_id)
        context={'object':notafiscal,'forms':'', 'error': ''}
        if request.method =="POST":
            notafiscal.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("controles:notasfiscais"))
    
    # NotaFiscal will throw a DoesNotExist exception if the result does not exist
    except NotaFiscal.DoesNotExist:
        context['error'] = 'NotaFiscal does not exist'
        
    except ProtectedError as e:
        context['error'] ='An error occured'
    
    return render(request,'controles/notafiscal_confirm_delete.html',context)
```

Though I don't see where `ProtectedError` is defined, but since you are not using django forms you can pass the error message to the context dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! It's Works!

Comment: You're welcome. If it does answer your question you can mark it as an answer